# Number of connections to tor via stem library - Controller creates 2 connections but closing the controller removes only one connection

Tags: python, tcp, tor, stem

I am working with the stem library and I'm writing a thin wrapper over the Stem Controller class.

I have some questions relating to the number of connections created when a controller is instantiated and how many are removed when the controller is closed.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import logging

import sys
import subprocess
from optparse import OptionParser

import stem
from stem.control import Controller

SOCKET_ERROR_CODE = 2
MISSING_PWD_ERROR_CODE = 3
PWD_FAIL_ERROR_CODE = 4
AUTH_FAIL_ERROR_CODE = 5
UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE = -1


class StemController():
    def __init__(self):
        # Added print statements for debugging - Yes, I know, shell=True is bad
        print(
            "[__init__ start] ",
            str(int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip()))
        )

        # Controller connection and credentials
        self.tor_router_ip = "127.0.0.1"
        self.tor_router_port = 9051
        self.tor_password = "controllportpassword"  # Add yours to test

        #  Create a controller - This might actually fail
        try:
            # Tried both and one at a time, still two connections
            self.controller = Controller.from_port(
                # address=self.tor_router_ip,
                 port=self.tor_router_port
            )
        except stem.SocketError as e:
            logging.info("SocketError when opening controller. Now existing with code %s." % (
                SOCKET_ERROR_CODE
            ))
            sys.exit(SOCKET_ERROR_CODE)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
            sys.exit(UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE)

        print(
            "[Controller created] ",
            str(int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip()))
        )

        # Authenticate controller - This might fail as well
        try:
            self.controller.authenticate(password=self.tor_password)
        except stem.connection.MissingPassword:
            logging.info(
                "MissingPassword when authenticating controller. Now existing with code %s." % MISSING_PWD_ERROR_CODE
            )
            self.controller.close()
            sys.exit(MISSING_PWD_ERROR_CODE)
        except stem.connection.PasswordAuthFailed:
            logging.info(
                "PasswordAuthFailed when authenticating controller. Now existing with code %s." % PWD_FAIL_ERROR_CODE
            )
            self.controller.close()
            sys.exit(PWD_FAIL_ERROR_CODE)
        except stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure:
            logging.info(
                "AuthenticationFailure when authenticating controller. Now existing with code %s." % AUTH_FAIL_ERROR_CODE
            )
            self.controller.close()
            sys.exit(AUTH_FAIL_ERROR_CODE)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
            self.controller.close()
            sys.exit(UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE)

        print(
            "[Controller auth] ",
            str(int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip()))
        )

    def __del__(self):
        init_tor_connections = int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip())
        print(
            "\nDeleting and cleaning up controller. Before cleanup there are %s tor connections." % init_tor_connections
        )

        self.controller.close()

        final_tor_connections = int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip())
        print(
            "After deletion of controller. After cleanup there are %s tor connections." % final_tor_connections
        )


import unittest


class TestStemController(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #  This is a darknet site that is almost always up
        self.up_site = "deepdot35wvmeyd5.onion"

    def test_stem_controller(self):
        # Make sure that the controller opens and closes correctly
        # Count how many connections on port 9051 we have
        pre_stem_controller = int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip())
        print("pre_stem_controller: ", pre_stem_controller)
        test_stem_controller = StemController()
        # Count how many connections on port 9051 we have after initializing the controller
        post_stem_controller = int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip())
        print("post_stem_controller: ", post_stem_controller)
        # We should have one more connection, since we created another once when we initialized the controller
        self.assertEqual(post_stem_controller, pre_stem_controller + 1)
        # Delete the controller
        del test_stem_controller
        # Count how many connections on port 9051 we have after deleting the controller
        post_del_stem_controller = int(subprocess.check_output('netstat -na | grep 9051 | wc -l', shell=True).strip())
        print("post_del_stem_controller: ", post_del_stem_controller)
        # We should have as many as we had in the beginning
        self.assertEqual(post_del_stem_controller, pre_stem_controller)


def suite():
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(TestStemController('test_stem_controller'))
    return test_suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = sys.argv[1:]
    parse = OptionParser("This is the stem controller script script.")
    parse.add_option(
        "-u",
        "--unittests",
        help="Action: Run unittests.",
        default=False,
        action='store_true'
    )

    (options, arguments) = parse.parse_args()

    if options.unittests:
        test_suite = suite()
        unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test_suite)
        logging.info("Unittests done. Now existing.")
        sys.exit()
```

TL;DR of code: Count number of connections on port 9051, create a controller, count number of connections on port 9051 again and assert the number increased by one. Same thing for deleting except assert connection count decreased by one.

I run my code with python3 stem_code.py -u and get, for example this:

```
pre_stem_controller:  1
[__init__ start]  1
[Controller created]  3
[Controller auth]  3
post_stem_controller:  3
F
Deleting and cleaning up controller. Before cleanup there are 3 tor connections.
After deletion of controller. After cleanup there are 2 tor connections.

======================================================================
FAIL: test_stem_controller (__main__.TestStemController)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  self.assertEqual(post_stem_controller, pre_stem_controller + 1)
AssertionError: 3 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.050s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

The most relevant part I think is this:

```
[__init__ start]  1
[Controller created]  3
```

**My first question is: Why are two connections created here?**

I have developed a theory why that is, but I am not sure.

Curious to see what those 2 connections are, I did this after instantiating the controller:

```
netstat -na | grep 9051
```

The result was this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9051          127.0.0.1:40606         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40606         127.0.0.1:9051          ESTABLISHED
```

So, I have the tor client listening on port 9051 ( first line ) and two connections, one from tor to stem ( 9051 to 40606, second row ) and one from stem to tor ( 40606 to 9051, third row ).

**Is this dual connection, tor to stem and stem to tor the reason two connections are created?**

Following this, I decided I would take the fact 2 connections are created *as is*. So I changed my unit test from +1 to +2 to pass that particular assertion. The test moved on but failed to pass the assertion that the number of connections pre initialisation is equal to the number of connections post deletion.

```
    self.assertEqual(post_del_stem_controller, pre_stem_controller)
AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

Using the same procedure as in the case of the connection, I did `netstat -na` and go this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9051          127.0.0.1:40636         TIME_WAIT
```

The tor to stem connection still appears to be around.

**Am I correct in thinking that when I do** `controller.close()` **I only close the stem to tor connection but the tor to stem connection remains active ( at least for a while, TIME_WAIT state )?**

Now, assuming I was correct so far:

1. Is there any way to force tor to close it's side of the connection?
2. Is there any reason to try to force tor to close it's connection? ( My reasoning goes like this. I know there are a maximum number of 256 connections to the tor client. I want to have as many of them free as possible ). Put otherwise, connections in state TIME_WAIT count as actual connection? For example, if I have 255 ESTABLISHED connections and one TIME_WAIT, will I still be able to make another connection to tor?
3. Do you think this is the correct way to test my wrapper class, or are there better ways of making sure the controller opens and closes correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The connection is closed as far as Tor is concerned.  That is, it has released that connection and no longer sees that client as connected.  When the socket is in `TIME_WAIT` state, the socket is closed but the OS keeps it around to ensure no late packets arrive from the old connection that might be accepted by a later connection from the same set of ports (e.g. 40606 from your example).

You can decrease the `TIME_WAIT` period in the OS, but it doesn't really address the problem.  See http://www.isi.edu/touch/pubs/infocomm99/infocomm99-web/ and http://www.linuxbrigade.com/reduce-time_wait-socket-connections/ for more info.

2. No.  Once you close the connection to the controller, Tor decreases the number of connected clients so it's freed up to accept more.  I wouldn't worry about it.
3. Probably not.  Why use netstat to test your connection when you can just issue a command to the controller and read a response?

The reason you see what looks like 3 connections, is because first is the listening socket on 9051, then when you connect, netstat is showing you both ends of the same connection (since it's local).  So you can see that there's a connection *to* Tor using port `40636`, and then you also (because it's a local connection) see the connection *from* your control client on port `40636` as well.  These two ends of the connection really represent a single connection.

So as long as you're connecting to a local Tor instance, the number of lines in netstat will increase by 2 for each connection.

You could eliminate the local client connection from the output by changing your grep to

```
netstat -ano|grep -E ':9051[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]'
```

You could then further filter out the LISTENING connection with:

```
netstat -ano|grep -E ':9051[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]'|grep -v 'LISTENING'
```

> Am I correct in thinking that when I do controller.close() I only
>   close the stem to tor connection but the tor to stem connection
>   remains active ( at least for a while, TIME_WAIT state )?

When you do `controller.close()`, both are closed.  Tor no longer sees the connection as open, it's just being held by the OS for the reason described above; to make sure that another connection using the same port combination doesn't get established and potentially accept lingering packets from the previous connection on the new one.  It's no longer open in Tor's eyes, it has removed the client from it's connection list.

Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you for the details response! This was very helpful.

Comment: @random_person_123 You're welcome! Let me know if you have more question!